# Perform conditional filtering based on grouped column value in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to perform filtering on Sales column such that for any Make-Auction group there should be atleast one sales is >= 100. So for Acura, Copart has 101 sales so both rows for Acura would be expected in output. For BMW, sales are <100 for both Copart and IAA, so it will be filtered out.

Dataframe:

```
Make    Auction Sales   
Acura   Copart  101
Acura   IAA     88  
BMW     Copart  50  
BMW     IAA     60
Buick   Copart  130 
Buick   IAA     140
```

Expected Output:

```
Make    Auction Sales   
Acura   Copart  101
Acura   IAA         88  
Buick   Copart  130 
Buick   IAA     140
```

I am able to apply a filter of >100 on entire Sales column, but it is not what I wanted. Any suggestion on how to perform this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [filtration](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
df = df.groupby('Make').filter(lambda x: x['Sales'].ge(100).any())
print (df)
    Make Auction  Sales
0  Acura  Copart    101
1  Acura     IAA     88
4  Buick  Copart    130
5  Buick     IAA    140
```

Another solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for `Make` values which are filtered by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print (df.loc[df['Sales'] >= 100, 'Make'])
0    Acura
4    Buick
5    Buick
Name: Make, dtype: object

print (df['Make'].isin(df.loc[df['Sales'] >= 100, 'Make']))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: Make, dtype: bool

df = df[df['Make'].isin(df.loc[df['Sales'] >= 100, 'Make'])]
print (df)
    Make Auction  Sales
0  Acura  Copart    101
1  Acura     IAA     88
4  Buick  Copart    130
5  Buick     IAA    140
```

Second solution is faster:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = list('abcdefghijklmno')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Make': np.random.choice(L, N),
                   'Sales':np.random.randint(110, size=N)})
print (df)

In [59]: %timeit df[df['Make'].isin(df.loc[df['Sales'] >= 100, 'Make'])]
10 loops, best of 3: 55.6 ms per loop

#Alexander answer
In [60]: %timeit df[df['Make'].isin(df[df['Sales'] >= 100]['Make'].unique())]
10 loops, best of 3: 65 ms per loop

In [61]: %timeit df.groupby('Make').filter(lambda x: x['Sales'].ge(100).any())
1 loop, best of 3: 217 ms per loop

#piRSquared solution 1
In [62]: %timeit df[df.Sales.ge(100).groupby([df.Make]).transform('any')]
1 loop, best of 3: 135 ms per loop

#piRSquared solution 2
In [63]: %%timeit
    ...: f, u = pd.factorize(df.Make.values)
    ...: w = df.Sales.values >= 100
    ...: df[(np.bincount(f, w) > 0)[f]]
    ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 67.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: 'faster' is entirely dependent on `N`, no?

Comment: sure, for better testing is necessary know number of unique values in `Make`, length of groups, length of dataframe. But obviously `loc` help performance.

Comment: The use of `loc` doesn't appear to hurt performance, but I would argue that the improvement is marginal.

Answer (score 2):

Filter the dataframe for the records where sales >= 100, then take the unique `Make` of cars.  Finally, use boolean indexing if any make is in this filtered set.

```
>>> df[df['Make'].isin(df[df['Sales'] >= 100]['Make'].unique())]
    Make Auction  Sales
0  Acura  Copart    101
1  Acura     IAA     88
4  Buick  Copart    130
5  Buick     IAA    140
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
`transform`
Using `'any'` returns `True` if any element is `True` within the group and broadcasts it across all indices in the group.

```
df[df.Sales.ge(100).groupby([df.Make]).transform('any')]

    Make Auction  Sales
0  Acura  Copart    101
1  Acura     IAA     88
4  Buick  Copart    130
5  Buick     IAA    140
```

---

**Option 2**
[**`pd.factorize`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) + [**`np.bincount`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html)
We use `np.bincount` to increment the bins from `pd.factorize` with the truth values determined by `df.Sales.values >= 100`.  If the bin is greater than `0` then we should take every element in the group defined by that bin.  We can get the appropriate array by slicing again by `f`.

This is very analogous to option 1.

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.Make.values)
w = df.Sales.values >= 100
df[(np.bincount(f, w) > 0)[f]]

    Make Auction  Sales
0  Acura  Copart    101
1  Acura     IAA     88
4  Buick  Copart    130
5  Buick     IAA    140
```

Comment: Interesting. Could you elaborate on `any` in the transform?